# NLog json fields missing when using a network target

Tags: nlog

I'm using NLog to log in json format, using the targets below (file and network).

When logging to the file target or both file and network, the messages are logged fine.

However, when using only the network target, dbResponseTime and messagesSentTotal will not be included in the message (in fact, any attribute using a layout with "event-properties:item="). All the other properties are present, including the one defined in the end (module).

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false" internalLogLevel="Off">

  <targets>
    <target name="logHealthCheck" xsi:type="File"
     fileName="D:\Logs\HealthCheck.${shortdate}.json"
     archiveFileName="D:\Logs\HealthCheck.{#}.json"
     archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
     archiveAboveSize="33554432"
     archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=o}" />
        <attribute name="machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
        <attribute name="environment" layout="${literal:text=DEV}" />
        <attribute name="dbResponseTime" layout="${event-properties:item=dbResponseTime}" encode="false"/>
        <attribute name="messagesSentTotal" layout="${event-properties:item=messagesSentTotal}" encode="false"/>
        <attribute name="module" layout="${literal:text=core}" />
      </layout>
    </target>

    <target name="logHealthCheckNetwork" xsi:type="Network" address="tcp://127.0.0.1:1514" newLine="true">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=o}" />
        <attribute name="machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
        <attribute name="environment" layout="${literal:text=DEV}" />
        <attribute name="dbResponseTime" layout="${event-properties:item=dbResponseTime}" encode="false"/>
        <attribute name="messagesSentTotal" layout="${event-properties:item=messagesSentTotal}" encode="false"/>
        <attribute name="module" layout="${literal:text=core}" />
      </layout>
    </target>

   <rules>
    <logger name="HealthCheck" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logHealthCheck,logHealthCheckNetwork">
      <filters>
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

Switched on the internal log, and no error is recorded. Trace below:

```
2018-02-02 16:43:07.7837 Trace Scanning LoggingRule 'logNamePattern: (HealthCheck:Equals) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] appendTo: [ logHealthCheckNetwork ]'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.7993 Trace  Scanning NetworkTarget 'Network Target[logHealthCheckNetwork]'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.8305 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''tcp://127.0.0.1:1514''
2018-02-02 16:43:07.8305 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9085 Trace    Scanning JsonAttribute 'NLog.Layouts.JsonAttribute'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9085 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''${date:universalTime=true:format=o}''
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9241 Trace      Scanning DateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${date}'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9397 Trace    Scanning JsonAttribute 'NLog.Layouts.JsonAttribute'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9397 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''${machinename}''
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9553 Trace      Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9553 Trace    Scanning JsonAttribute 'NLog.Layouts.JsonAttribute'
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9709 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''${literal:text=DEV}''
2018-02-02 16:43:07.9709 Trace      Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-02-02 16:43:08.0177 Trace    Scanning JsonAttribute 'NLog.Layouts.JsonAttribute'
2018-02-02 16:43:08.0333 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''${event-properties:item=dbResponseTime}''
2018-02-02 16:43:08.0333 Trace      Scanning EventPropertiesLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${event-properties}'
2018-02-02 16:43:08.0801 Trace    Scanning JsonAttribute 'NLog.Layouts.JsonAttribute'
2018-02-02 16:43:08.0801 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''${event-properties:item=messagesSentTotal}''
2018-02-02 16:43:08.3453 Trace    Scanning JsonAttribute 'NLog.Layouts.JsonAttribute'
2018-02-02 16:43:08.3609 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''${literal:text=core}''
2018-02-02 16:43:08.3765 Trace      Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
```

Comment: How do you write only to the network-target? Cannot see how that is possible with the posted logging-rules.

Comment: Could you create a reproducable case and create an issue at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues

Comment: Added https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2569

Answer (score 0):

NLog 4.5.4 has been released that fixes the issue: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2573